# Plot a smooth graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

In R I want to Plot a smooth graph (with its shadowed margin) which contains “age” and “circumference” variables on X and Y-axis for ready Orange data

What is “method” of smoothing which ggplot2 uses?

I do like this but get erros:

```
x <- Orange[2]
y <- Orange[3]
lo <- loess(y~x)
plot(x,y)
lines(predict(lo), col='red', lwd=2)
```

> Error(s), warning(s): Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x) : 
>   invalid type (list) for variable 'y' Calls: loess -> eval -> eval ->
>    -> model.frame.default Execution halted

Comment: Since we do not have your Orange data, we cannot run your code.

Comment: you are, likely, getting that error as the `x` and `y` variables are one-columns dataframes, but you want to pass them to `loess` as vectors. So try using `x <- Orange[[2]] ; y <- Orange[[3]]` (note the double square brackets). Also, `loess` has a `data` argument, so you can use the names of the variables (of columns 2 & 3) in the formula, and add `data=Orange`. So for your example, `lo  = loess(circumference ~ age, data=Orange) ; 
lines(lo$x[order(lo$x)], predict(lo)[order(lo$x)], col='red', lwd=2)`

Answer (score 3):

From ?geom_smooth:
"for [the default] the smoothing method is chosen based on the size of the largest group (across all panels). ‘loess()’ is used for less than 1,000 observations; otherwise ‘mgcv::gam()’ is used"

So for Orange you will get loess anyway, but you can be explicit by setting the method.

```
ggplot(Orange,aes(x=age,y=circumference))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="loess")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use geom_smooth(). Example as below.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat,y=price)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=cut))+
  geom_smooth()
```